# Ocultar salida del comando groupadd

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Cómo hago para que la salida del `groupadd` no se imprima, cuando el grupo ya existe, o sea que no muestre el mensaje:

`groupadd: group 'grupo' already exists`

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es ocultar la salida de error, el *stderr*, redirige esa salida al archivo `/dev/null`.

```
groupadd grupo 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX Si te sirvió mi respuesta, deberías marcarla como la acertada para que sirva de referencia a demás usuarios que tengan una pregunta similar.

Comment: My bad! Tienes razón, lo olvidé. Gracias de nuevo